# unknown uri delete android draft

Tags: android, sms

My problem is that when I try to delete android draft from draft box using code below I face with the unknown URI . I search a lot but I did not found my answer . 
Any one can help me ?

my code is :

```
 getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"),
        "_id=?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(draftID)});
```

Thanks in advance ;

Comment: I think the correct URI is content://sms/drafts/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i test your URI and agin i have unknown uri :-(